# same javascript not working on similar elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, textcolor

IDK why, but the script is working for `#last_name` and not for `#first_name`

`last_name` is just as it is supposed to be, but not the `first_name`
Please explain the solution, I inspected the code and did all I could.

```js
//i also worked on an alternative code but it only worked one time:
//here is the code that worked only once 

let first_name = document.getElementById("first_name");
let last_name = document.getElementById("last_name");
const color_swap = () => {
  first_name.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  last_name.style.color = "rgb(254, 215, 3)";
  setInterval(() => {
    first_name.style.color = "rgb(254, 215, 3)";
    last_name.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  }, 2000);
};
window.addEventListener("load", color_swap);


//so how do i iterate it?
```

```js
// ---------home----------
let first_name = document.getElementById('first_name');
let last_name = document.getElementById('last_name');
first_name.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
const color_swap = () => setInterval(()=>{
    first_name.style.color = first_name.style.color == 'rgb(255,255,255)' ? 'rgb(254, 215, 3)' : 'rgb(255,255,255)';
    last_name.style.color = last_name.style.color == 'rgb(254, 215, 3)' ? 'rgb(255,255,255)' : 'rgb(254, 215, 3)';
},1000);
window.addEventListener('load', color_swap);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap");
/* ---------------css reset------------ */
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/*-----------------------------*/
.home {
  height: 35rem;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0rem 12rem;
}
.text h1{
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.text p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a300e81b2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="home" id="home">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Hi, I am</p>
        <h1 id="first_name">Harsh <span id="last_name">Sunwani</span></h1>
        <p>A Web Developer in Training</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Random text in a question is never a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the values of the `x.style.color` before the comparison?

Comment: You have included a huge chunk of css which looks unrelated to your question, making people who want to help you spend extra effort to investigate what is not relevant. Also you include links to external css and js files, and as we don't now what they contain we won't know how those affect your problem. Isolate and reduce your question to just the relevant parts that cause your problem, and in many cases while doing this you might discover the cause of the problem yourself.

Comment: i thought that i should give all the details so i provided the css reset code too and the random text was so that i could post it or it wont allow me too ... i'll keep these details in mind

Comment: @A_A can you pls show what u meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```js
let first_name = document.getElementById("first_name");
let last_name = document.getElementById("last_name");
const color_swap = () => {
  let whitefirst = true;
  setInterval(() => {
    if (whitefirst) {
      first_name.style.color = "rgb(254, 215, 3)";
      last_name.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    } else {
      first_name.style.color = "rgb(255,255,255)";
      last_name.style.color = "rgb(254, 215, 3)";
    }
    whitefirst = !whitefirst;
  }, 2000);
};

window.addEventListener("load", color_swap);
```

```css
.home {
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
}
.text h1{
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.text p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="home" id="home">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Hi, I am</p>
    <h1>
      <span id="first_name" style="color:white">Harsh</span>
      <span id="last_name" style="color:#fed703">Sunwani</span>
    </h1>
    <p>A Web Developer in Training</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

1. To swap colors continuously, you need a flag to indicate whether it is in state A or in state B. The flag I use is named `whitefirst`.
2. After each iteration, you have to toggle the flag. I do it  by simply negating it, so if it is true it becomes false, and if it is false it becomes true.
3. You encapsulate `last_name` within `first_name` in `<h1>`. When you change the properties of `first_name`, they will apply to `last_name` at the same time. While it works for this instance, it might have unintended consequence if your requirements change even slightly. So, no harm splitting the two as independent elements (two `<span>`s).

Comment: bro this aint working at all....its the same as the alternative code i gave above

Comment: @HarshS11 Does working = changing colors of first and last names around, from white/yellow to yellow/white?

Comment: it is supposed to continuously swap colors

Comment: This answer, while it mimics the OP's first attempt, doesn't appear to do what the OP actually wants(swap two css colors for elements).  Rather, it sets one color and then continuously sets another, every five seconds.  Not really sure why you're continuously setting a color that doesn't change.  Not to mention the fact that the OP asked for an explanation, and this is just a code dump.  It doesn't even have comments.

Comment: @Daedalus i actually this is just a part of the entire code ...... which goes along the theme of continuous change

Comment: @HarshS11 Updated answer.

Comment: @Daedalus Original code by OP couldn't even run *Uncaught TypeError", so I could only guess what he was wanting to do. Now that you have clarified, I have updated the answer.

Comment: While I am uncertain why the OP replied to me to say something that is possibly not relevant to the question(You can't @ two people at once, so...), the second example they gave did work, even if not completely.  That said, this answer still lacks an explanation and is a code dump.  Even if the OP does understand what you did, it's always a good idea to explain what you did. @OldGeezer

Comment: @Daedalus  the above one was not my main code but it did what i wanted one time...... the below snippet is running fine...... anyways thanks for ur time and efforts both of you, OldGeezer